# How to clear a WebForms page after a button event?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have one button called export, on click on that button one zip file is created, inside that multiple folders, so there is no problem over there.

The problem is that I want, after the click event occurred, I want my (aspx) page to clear and the button also be disabled on the screen and one message appears that export successful.

But only zip file created. Can any one please help me with this.

Here is my code:

```cs
protected void btnExport1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");           

        string directoryPath = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsageExportPath"] + "UsageExport_" + sqlFormattedDate;  // Set Directory Path
        string zipFileName = "UsageExport_" + sqlFormattedDate + ".zip"; // Set Zip File Name

        createDirectory(directoryPath);
        CreateZip(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsageExportPath"] + zipFileName, 
        directoryPath);               

        RemoveDirectory(directoryPath); // Delete Directory.                     

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=" + zipFileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblResult.Text = "Usage Exported SuccessFully";
        exportResultPanel.Visible = true;
        usagePanel.Visible = false;       

        Response.WriteFile(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsageExportPath"] + zipFileName);

        Response.End();
        //Response.Redirect("Receipt.aspx", false);
    }
```

Comment: My suspicion is that the response headers being sent back to browser make it think the only thing that's being returned is the zip file, and that no page changes are included in the response.  I would make the zip file download method do only that, respond with the zip file.  When that zip file is received, the webpage should update itself (probably using javascript) to change the UI.

Comment: yes if  i remove that  zip creation  code it works, but i want both  the things

Comment: The point is that you **cannot** return both a file *and* update the UI in a single response.  You could follow these steps:  1) Create the file and save it in a temporary location on the server.  2) Respond to the website with a success/failure response, and include a URI to the temporary server location.  3) Make a download request (like you currently have) with that location as a parameter, serve the file and delete the file on server when it's been served.  Alternatively, you could as I said before, update your UI via javascript, and just provide the download only.

Comment: @DanRayson Yes, you can. Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948957/how-to-let-a-asp-net-page-know-when-a-file-is-ready-for-download-from-the-server/59010319#59010319

Comment: @dpant That answer is a pretty darn round-about way of including a response with extra data in it when serving a download response...  While you can include a cookie in the response with extra data, is it desirable?  It feels very messy to me.  I think I stand by my original response but I might change the wording to "...you **shouldn't** return both file..."  In the end, it's *still* javascript that'll be updating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in the end

```
btnExport1.Enabled = false;
```

and add a server side label on aspx page whose id may be label1, then add this line below the my first line:

```
label1.Text = "Export successful";
```

Comment: lblResult.Text = "Usage Exported SuccessFully";

Answer (score 0):

You can send a cookie along with the zip file to the client and let him know when to update the UI.

For details read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59010319/313935) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948957/how-to-let-a-asp-net-page-know-when-a-file-is-ready-for-download-from-the-server).