# CEFsharp : code that tells the site page that the browser window is open on the entire page?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, cefsharp

First of all, sorry for any mistakes, because English is my second language.

I am currently working on a browser project using (CEFsharp winform C#) to open the page and save it offline, but I encountered a problem with sites that do not display the content until the user moves the browser window to the content, so my question is: Can I put a code that tells the site page that the browser window is open on the entire page to download all Content?

I hope you can help me with this, because I have been searching for more than a week in this topic and could not find anything.

Comment: You can check out this URL which provide way to detect page download in small chunk.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676152/how-can-i-detect-when-a-file-download-has-completed-in-asp-net

Comment: What do you mean by user moves the browser window to the content?